# Mapbox doesn't cluster at top level zoom

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have copied the mapbox example from here;

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster-html/

When I run it from my server though the map loads, but clustering doesn't seem to work.
If I zoom in, I see the individual records, but no zoomed out clustering. If you zoom in enough around Spain you will see the records.

http://75.9.250.45:8011/mrcjava/servlet/SQL_CT_01.I00090s

I have simply copied and pasted the code from the example into my own html, so I'm unsure why it would behave differently than the example does

Comment: I've copied the exact same code onto JS fiddle, and it works as per the Mapbox example. But when I run it from my server... I don't get the clustering.  https://jsfiddle.net/sparx1981/a9cbhx1d/2/

Answer (score 0):

This was due to freemarker causing errors with some of the code. Wrapping these as per the below solved it

${r'${w}'} instead of ${w}.